# Excel VBA - populate cells in one column based on values in another one

Tags: excel, vba

First of all, sorry for being blunt - I'm just starting my adventure with coding, and I sort of stuck on the problem below...

I have a file in which there are product names and their prices.
The names of the products are repetitive, and so are their prices.
I would like to have a macro that would read the column contaning product names (B), and then copy the prices from column C, so that all products with the same name have the same price. After that, the macro should put zeroes in all rows contaning product name and price (columns D to F).

I've spent last two days wrapping my head around this idea, but the only thing I seem to get right is this bit:

```
price = Range("C2").Value
If price > 0 Then
Range("D2:F2") = 0
End If
```

I can repeat this for all rows, that's not a problem... but the first part of the problem eludes me by what seems to be light-years.

Is there a simple solution I've been missing?

[What the file looks before:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q2mZq.png)

[What it should look like after:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVcbA.png)

Edit: 
I have also a terribly crude and cumbersome solution to copy the prices:

```
If Range("B5") = Range("B2") Then
Range("C2").Select
Range("C2").Copy
Range("C5").Select
Range("C5").PasteSpecial
End If
```

But I realze that this would require a constant number of products (not the case - can be 2, can be two dozen)... so I am not happy with that.

Comment: You just need a VLOOKUP formula, no need for VBA.

Comment: @SJR - okay, I suppose I could do It for VLOOKUP, but a macro is still the thing I am aiming at - consider it to be mock of a solution that other users of the same excel sheet may use, who have next-to-no knowledge of VLOOKUP

Comment: You could record a macro of you inserting the formula and then go from there. A combination of INDEX and MATCH might be better in your situation as you are copying multiple columns.

Comment: Hi Matthew, If I were doing this, I would have created a separate table with the prices of each product.  I could help you create something that will read the prices from Column C, but what would you do if you ever had two different prices for the same product?

Comment: @TempleGuard527 - "what would you do if you ever had two different prices fro the same product" - actually, in this case, this is NOT going to happen, ever :)

Answer (score 1):

I made quickly just looking the photo what you are expecting, see if is like this.

```
    Dim vLR As Long, vC, l, c  'l = line and c= column

    vLR = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row 'vLR =  variable Last Row

    vC = 0 'vC = variable Columns you have
    c = 4 ' starting on the 4 column
    Do While vC < 3 '3 columns availability /ordered/sold
        l = 2
        Do While vLR >= l
            If Cells(l, c) = "" Then
                Cells(l, c) = 0
            End If
            l = l + 1
        Loop
        c = c + 1
        vC = vC + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! that actually solves a half of my conundrum :) Your code populates correct cells with zeroes, so the "only" thing left is to populate the prices based on the unique names of products...

Comment: with that you can use a vlookup or input a new tab in your excel with the macro :)

Comment: Thanks again :) I'll look into handling this as you suggested - though a macro, and staying within the same tab, is still my perfect goal :)

Comment: @Lucas I recommend always to use meaningful variable names: Makes it much easier for humans to read (computer doesn't care anyway) and therefore leads into less errors and better maintenance of the code. Just as an example with `LastRow` vs. `vLR` •  `ColumnsCount` vs. `vC`  or  `iRow` for a row iterator • `iCol` for a column iterator your code would be almost readable like a human readable text. That's just a suggestion.